# Alternative to use localtorage in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am getting following error on my JSP page when I use localstorage

localstorage is undefined

Following is the sample JSP code

```
     if(localstorage['ScriptActivityHelpSectionHidden']!='undefined')
 {
     helpSectionHidden=localstorage['ScriptActivityHelpSectionHidden'];
     if(helpSectionHidden=='true')
     { 
         setEditorWidthForActivity(helpId);
     }else
     {
         $("#helpId").show(); 
     }
 }
```

Comment: This isn't JSP code; this is Javascript. Local storage takes place on the clients; its part of the browser and only exists in new browsers and can be turned off by the user. The alternative is to use storage on your server, i.e. a database; use AJAX, in other words.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Answer (score 1):

You have not spelled it correctly, case matters: `localStorage`

Comment: This is correct.  Also to know if it is supported see: http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage

Comment: Yes, and fortunately it is very well supported these days.